# How do incremental imaging programs know what changed?

Tags: windows, backup, ntfs, incremental-backup, imaging

When you tell an imaging program like Macrium Reflect to create an incremental backup, how does it figure out which clusters have changed on the volume since the last backup?
For example, does it look at the file layout or the USN journal? Or does it use VSS somehow?

Is there any possibility of it being incorrect? For example, if I change the file date, will it get confused? Or what if I defragment the disk, causing files to get moved around without changing? Or what if I disable the USN journal? etc.

Comment: This would vary by the program. Some will look at USN journal, some (most?) will just compare file timestamps and sizes, some will hash files and compare the hashes. It's better ask on Macrium forums, perhaps?

Comment: @Angstrom: I can't ask on their forum (you need a paid version for them to allow you to register), and in any case I'd like to know what approaches different programs actually take, not just Macrium.